# SQL - Multiple Table Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi maybe someone can help me here ...
I have a slight problem with an SQL Statement. ( On MS - SQL Server 2008)
So i have 6 Tables looking like this

ID / Company / Month / ClosedTimeStamp / Different Information

Now i need (preferrable in one Statement :P) the count of Datasets from each table grouped by Company and Month at the time it looks something like this.
And there is another thing not all tables need to have data for that Company and that Month so there can be 0 as Result for count(*)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c, Month, Company 
FROM Table1  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
GROUP BY Company, Month 
ORDER BY Company
```

I can do this for all the tables and just pick out the results for each company ... Well if someone has any Idea i really would appreciate it :)

Sorry forgot something ... the result should look like this:

Company / Month / CountTable1 / CountTable2 / CountTable3 / .....
Test       02        1              0               50

If it's not possible in one statement well then i have to make it work another way. :)

Thanks

Lim

Comment: You have six tables with nearly the same structure? And your `ORDER BY` above should probably order by `Company` and not `Firma` ;)

Comment: Ah sorry :P forgot to replace that

Comment: Of course, it is possible in one statement. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your DB was normalized the query would be much simpler.

Because, your `company` and `Month` are spread across 6 tables, we need to make `union` of those tables in order to get the distinct dataset of all `company`+`month`, as such:

```
select company, month from table1
 union
select company, month from table2
 union
select company, month from table3
 union
select company, month from table4
 union
select company, month from table5
 union
select company, month from table6
```

Note, that we need `union`, not `union all`, because we don't want the same company+month pair repeated.

Then, just use this dataset to query the quantities for each table:

```
select t.company, t.month,
    (select count(*) from table1
      where company = t.company
        and month = t.month
        and ClosedTimeStamp is null) as qt1,
    (select count(*) from table2 
      where company = t.company
        and month = t.month
        and ClosedTimeStamp is null) as qt2,
    (select count(*) from table3
      where company = t.company 
        and month = t.month
        and ClosedTimeStamp is null) as qt3,
    (select count(*) from table4
      where company = t.company
        and month = t.month
        and ClosedTimeStamp is null) as qt4,
    (select count(*) from table5
      where company = t.company
        and month = t.month
        and ClosedTimeStamp is null) as qt5,
    (select count(*) from table6
      where company = t.company
        and month = t.month
        and ClosedTimeStamp is null) as qt6
from (
  select company, month from table1
   union
  select company, month from table2
   union
  select company, month from table3
   union
  select company, month from table4
   union
  select company, month from table5
   union
  select company, month from table6
) t
order by t.company
```

Answer (score 2):

UNION ALL table rows and then do the count

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c, Month, Company 
FROM 
(
SELECT Month,Company FROM Table1  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Month,Company FROM Table2  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Month,Company FROM Table3  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Month,Company FROM Table4  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Month,Company FROM Table5  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Month,Company FROM Table6  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
) AS t
GROUP BY Company, Month 
ORDER BY Company
```

If you want the total for each table,company in one row

```
SELECT SUM(t1) t1,SUM(t2) t2,SUM(t3) t3,SUM(t4) t4,SUM(t5) t5,SUM(t6) t6, Month, Company 
FROM 
(
SELECT Month,Company, 1 t1,0 t2, 0 t3, 0 t4, 0 t5, 0 t6 FROM Table1  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Month,Company, 0 t1,1 t2, 0 t3, 0 t4, 0 t5, 0 t6 FROM Table2  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Month,Company, 0 t1,0 t2, 1 t3, 0 t4, 0 t5, 0 t6 FROM Table3  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Month,Company, 0 t1,0 t2, 0 t3, 1 t4, 0 t5, 0 t6 FROM Table4  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Month,Company, 0 t1,0 t2, 0 t3, 0 t4, 1 t5, 0 t6 FROM Table5 WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT Month,Company, 0 t1,0 t2, 0 t3, 0 t4, 0 t5, 1 t6 FROM Table6  WHERE ClosedTimeStamp IS NULL
) AS t
GROUP BY Company, Month 
ORDER BY Company
```

Comment: This just gets me a Count over all Tables/Companys not what i'm looking for The result should look like this

Company / Month / CountTable1 / CountTable2 / CountTable3 / .....
Test       02        1              0               50

Comment: You forgot to correct the name of the tables. Its not always `Table1`